# Why @Valid Class it fails if I create a repository?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have this controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="admin/departamento", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView departamentoGuardar(
            @Valid Departamento departamento ,
            BindingResult br
    ){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("costos/departamento");
        return mav;
    }
```

...and it is working.

But, if I build a empty repository class:

```
@Repository("departamentoRepository")
public interface DepartamentoRepository extends JpaRepository<Departamento, Integer>{


}
```

My controller throws this when a put a `String` and only accepts `int`:

> org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert
>   value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'com.carrduci.gestionycontrol.model.Departamento'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for
>   value 'asdf'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For
>   input string: "asdf"  at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:80)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:52)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:692)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttributeFromRequestValue(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:141)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE

My Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "departamento")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Departamento.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM Departamento d")})
public class Departamento implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id_departamento")
    private Integer idDepartamento;
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "departamento")
    private String departamento;

    public Departamento() {
    }

    public Departamento(Integer idDepartamento) {
        this.idDepartamento = idDepartamento;
    }

    public Integer getIdDepartamento() {
        return idDepartamento;
    }

    public void setIdDepartamento(Integer idDepartamento) {
        this.idDepartamento = idDepartamento;
    }

    public String getDepartamento() {
        return departamento;
    }

    public void setDepartamento(String departamento) {
        this.departamento = departamento;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idDepartamento != null ? idDepartamento.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Departamento)) {
            return false;
        }
        Departamento other = (Departamento) object;
        if ((this.idDepartamento == null && other.idDepartamento != null) || (this.idDepartamento != null && !this.idDepartamento.equals(other.idDepartamento))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.carrduci.gestionycontrol.model.Departamento[ idDepartamento=" + idDepartamento + " ]";
    }

}
```

---

### **UPDATE**

```html
<th:block th:include="fragments/encabezados :: encabezados"></th:block> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-0">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12"> <h4>Departamento</h4></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 ">
                        <form th:action="${departamento.idDepartamento>0}? 
                                                @{/costos/admin/departamento/modificar}:
                                                @{/costos/admin/departamento}" 
                                                method="post" th:object="${departamento}">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-xs-12">

                                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{idDepartamento}">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Nombre</i></span>
                                        <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" th:field="*{departamento}"> 
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('departamento')}" th:errors="*{departamento}" ></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
                                    <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger BOTON_LIMPIAR" href="/index"> <span class="  glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancelar</a>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> 
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span> 
                                        <span th:text="${departamento.idDepartamento>0}? 
                                                            @{Modificar}:
                                                            @{Guardar}">
                                        </span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form> 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 ">
                        <hr>
                        <th:block   th:include="fragments/tabla :: tabla"></th:block>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>

    </div>
<th:block th:include="fragments/pieDePagina :: pieDePagina"></th:block>
```

Comment: I think the error comes from your view. can you add a code snippet from there.

Comment: @pDer666 ok. It's updated

Comment: The exception says that input string 'asdf' could not converted to Integer. Wherr did you input 'asdf'? I think somewhere an input field is mapped to an integer field of the class

Comment: The problem is the input "*{departamento}".  In my class is a string.

Comment: I do not know why, but I put the fields back in the html and it works. What is this about? The name does not correspond to the information it captures.

Comment: But it does´t save the information of the second field, only the id.